# Java, problem sending a message with socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, client, message

I have a problem with my Java program. It has a socket connection between a server and many client. Here is the server (the part which concerns the problem):

```
private static ArrayList<ParallelServer> clientConnected = new ArrayList<ParallelServer>();


public Server(int port) {
    this.port = port;
    if (!startServer())
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(""),
                "Error!", "ERROR!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

private boolean startServer() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        loadDatabase();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}

public void runServer() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            client = server.accept();
            ParallelServer pServer = new ParallelServer(client);
            clientConnected.add(pServer);
            Thread thread = new Thread(pServer);
            thread.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public static void sendBroadcast(String username) throws IOException {
    for(int i = 0; i < clientConnected.size(); i++)
        clientConnected.get(i).sendAnswer("@change," + username);
}
```

The parallel server is:

```
    private Socket client;
    private InputStreamReader inputstreamreader;
    private BufferedReader bufferedreader;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;

    public ParallelServer(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
            bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            String lineread = "";

            while (client.isConnected()) {
                lineread = bufferedreader.readLine();
                doCommand(lineread);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException unhe) {
        } catch (InterruptedIOException intioe) {
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendAnswer(String answer) throws IOException {
        printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        printwriter.println(answer);
        printwriter.flush();
    }
```

And here is the client:

```
private String serverurl = "localhost";
private int serverport = 7777;
private PrintWriter printwriter;
private InputStreamReader inputstreamreader;
private BufferedReader bufferedreader;
private Socket server;

public Client() {
    server = null;
    try {
        server = new Socket(serverurl, serverport);
        server.setSoTimeout(5000);
    } catch (UnknownHostException unhe) {
        System.out.println("UnknownHostException: " + unhe.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedIOException intioe) {
        System.out.println("Timeout while attempting to establish socket connection.");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Unable to reach the server!","ERROE!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public String sendCommand(String command) throws IOException {
    if(server == null) {
        try {
            server = new Socket(serverurl, serverport);
            server.setSoTimeout(5000);
        } catch (UnknownHostException unhe) {
            System.out.println("UnknownHostException: " + unhe.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedIOException intioe) {
            System.out.println("Timeout while attempting to establish socket connection.");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Unable to reach the server!","ERROR!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    if(server != null) {
        printwriter = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
        printwriter.println(command);
        printwriter.flush();
        inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream());
        bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

        return bufferedreader.readLine();
    }
    else
        return "@serverProblem";
}
```

The program is a simple online game with turns. Players' turns are created with a queue and when a player passes his turn, the server send a broadcast message which say "Now it is 'Player 1' turn." (for instance). My problem is that when a client receive the message, its like it add the answer "Now it is 'Player 1' turn." to the next message it will receive. In my case: when a player passes his turn, he sends "@passTurn,username". The ParallelServer class polls it from the queue, puts it at the bottom of the queue, sends the client "@ok" to tell it that the turn has changed successfully and tells the Server class to send the broadcast message. Then, when the same client will try do do a further action, it will consider "Now it is 'Player 1' turn." as the answer the server has given to it. Instead, I would like that the server and the clients work as always and when the broadcast message is cought, the client is notified without any collateral effect.
What can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Is your output in console or an IDE? Also, are you sure you are not looking at the previous message being buffered?

Comment: @Vern: my output is an IDE. About the buffer, it happens something like this: client sends "@passTurn" -> server sends "@ok" -> client receives it -> server then sends "@changeTurn,player1" (the client do nothing, since it has not send a message and it is not waiting for an answer) -> client sends "@otherAction" and reads "@changeTurn,player1" as answer.

Comment: So, at which point in that message exchange is it failing?

Comment: I want that the client detects "@changeTurn,player1", and by now it can't since it detects an answer only with the class that used 'sendCommand'. Every class that uses it do like: "I send this and then I receive this". But for the broadcast message there is no "I send this", since the server sends it without receiving any order by the client, so there is no "I receive this". Even if I will put an 'if else' in "readAnswer" (if(...readLine().contains("changeTurn"))..), it is not detected because "readAnswer" has not been called by any class (the client does not know "@changeTurn" will be sent).

Comment: That being the case, it sounds more like you need to change your message passing mechanism. Also, you might want to look into a non-blocking bi-directional message as suggested in my reply below. It's too much text to put in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bi-directional message passing mechanism should look something like this:

Server:

```
Wait on any client InputStream
if (broadcast) 
  broadcast_message()
else 
  process_message()
```

Client:

```
Receiving Thread:
Wait on server broadcast

Sending Thread:
Wait on messages to be sent to server from the User Input
```

This should do the trick :)

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: I can't write the server in this way, since the broadcast message isn't sent after an InputStream. I tried to organize the client as you suggested, creating a new Thread to wait for the broadcast message, but the bufferedreader is messed up (my idea was to read from the same input stream on two different bufferedreader, but it doesn't work). Maybe I should try using mutex for this purpose.

Comment: Done with a thread which constantly listen to the server. Using an if(bufferedreader.isReady()) and reading the answer each 3 seconds, the communication work properly. Anyway, thanks for giving me the idea of using two different threads! :)

Comment: Hey no worries! Glad that you managed to get things working and I'm always glad to help! Cheers!